# Cannot add products in admin panel. "Permission denied" exception error message

Tags: product, admin, installation, dashboard, magento2.3.1

I've recently setup and installed Magento 2, but am having issues adding products to the site. when I click to add a product I get the following exception error:

> Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Can't create directory
>   /var/www/html/gdprmk.co.uk/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice/.
>   Class
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice\Interceptor
>   generation error: The requested class did not generate properly,
>   because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If ---
>   after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the
>   'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested
>   class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class
>   object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

I tried to manually create the Tierprice folder with 755 permissions but then I get the following error message:

> Exception #0 (RuntimeException): The specified
>   "/var/www/html/gdprmk.co.uk/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice/Interceptor.php.9261"
>   file couldn't be written.
>   Warning!file_put_contents(/var/www/html/gdprmk.co.uk/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice/Interceptor.php.9261):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied Class
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice\Interceptor
>   generation error: The requested class did not generate properly,
>   because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If ---
>   after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the
>   'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested
>   class did not generate

The folder had 755 permissions if that helps! Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have write access for generated directory

Execute this as a root user

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 any help thanks @Raj Mohan R